# Change background colour of element upon hover css

Tags: html, css, colors, hover, background-color

I have some some HTML and CSS that's makes up a rectangle. Essentially I want to make it so when you hover over the square it changes colour. I've tried doing it already but it doesn't work.

Here is the HTML for that element:

```
<div id="teamspeak_box"><a href="ts3server://craft412.serveminecraft.net:9987">
                                                                                                </div>

                   <div id="teamspeak_box_2"></div>

                   <div id="teamspeak_text">
                                   <p>TEAMSPEAK<P/>
                               </div>


                   <div id="teamspeak_image"> 
                                           <img src="images/CRAFT412 - Box - Teamspeak.png" alt="TEAMSPEAK">
                                      </div>
```

Also here is the CSS

```
#teamspeak_box a:hover {background: #C62828;
                        transition: all 0.5s ease;}

#teamspeak_text {color: white;
                 bottom: 93px;
                 right: 66px;
                 position: absolute;}          

#teamspeak_image {bottom: 80px;
                  right: 104px;
                  position: absolute;}

#teamspeak_box {width: 159px;
                height: 43px;
                background: #212121;
                bottom: 82px;
                right: 76px;
                position: absolute;
                border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;}

#teamspeak_box_2 {width: 43px;
                  height: 43px;
                  background:#313131;
                  bottom: 82px;
                  right: 191px;
                  position: absolute;
                  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML/CSS to this (if this is what you are looking)

```css
#teamspeak_box {
    display: block;
    width: 159px;
    height: 43px;
    background: #212121;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 76px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#teamspeak_box:hover {
    background: #C62828;
}
#teamspeak_box a {
    display: block;
    height: 43px;
}
#teamspeak_box_2 {
    display: block;
    width: 43px;
    height: 43px;
    background:#313131;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}
#teamspeak_image {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
#teamspeak_text {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family:arial;
}
```

```html
<div id="teamspeak_box">
    <a href="ts3server://craft412.serveminecraft.net:9987">
        <span id="teamspeak_box_2"></span>
        <span id="teamspeak_text">TEAMSPEAK</span>
        <img  id="teamspeak_image" src="//dummyimage.com/33x33" alt="TEAMSPEAK"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ru3r8ad2/)

Answer (score 0):

this is html .....

```
<div class="divone">

</div>
```

this is css..

```
div.divone{
background-color:red;
}

div.divone:hover{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

I hope this will help..